# ObjectBox can't build project with inheritance

Tags: android, greendao, objectbox

I created two objects. one extends the other.
The parent object has an ID as it written in the `ObjectBox` documentation, but I can't build the project with the error of:

```
Error:[ObjectBox] Code generation failed: No ID property found for "Entity FastCacheData" (use @Id on a property of type long)
```

**CacheData:**

```
@Entity
public class CacheData {
    @Id
    private long id;
    @Index
    private String key;
    @Index
    private Date expirationDate;
    private Date lastUpdated;

    public CacheData(String key, Date expirationDate) {
        this.lastUpdated = new Date();
        this.key = key;
        this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
    }
}
```

**FastCacheData:**

```
@Entity
public class FastCacheData extends CacheData {
    private String fullName;
    private String thumbnailUrl;
    private boolean isSpam;

    @Convert(converter = DataSource.DataSourceConverter.class, dbType = Integer.class)
    private DataSource photoDataSource;

    @Convert(converter = DataSource.DataSourceConverter.class, dbType = Integer.class)
    private DataSource nameDataSource;

    public FastCacheData(String key, Date expirationDate, String fullName, DataSource nameDataSource, String thumbnailUrl, DataSource photoDataSource, boolean isSpam) {
        super(key, expirationDate);
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.nameDataSource = nameDataSource;
        this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
        this.photoDataSource = photoDataSource;
        this.isSpam = isSpam;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymorphism of entities is not supported at this time, but there is a [feature request](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/5).